# Google Analytics API Quota Increase failed

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, quota

I recently applied to have the limit the Google Analytics API increased. This was approved and I received an email saying it was completed. When I went to check the increase it still showed the original value. I navigated across from the Developer Console to the GCP console and saw a message saying that Quota cannot not be increased when still using the Free Credits. So I changed the account to a paid one, hoping that the increase would then show. But alas, I am still stuck with the lower quota. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Related issue in Google's tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72354872

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved internally with Google